# In d3js, how to plot line chart from csv file, taking data from seperate columns for each row

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am new to d3js. I have data in csv file. The data in csv file is something like this:

Name,val1,val2,val3,val4
x,5,4,8,2
y,10,5,4,13
z,7,3,2,11

I need to plot line chart for each row depending upon choice selected, i.e a chart for x with values 5,4,8 or for y with corresponding values & so on.

Here is the code I am working on:

```
var slots=["0-6", "6-12", "12-18", "18-23"];

newdata = rawdata.filter(function(d)
{
return (d["Name"] == ch);
});

maxval = d3.max(rawdata, function(d)
{
    return Math.max(d["Val1"],d["Val2"],d["Val3"],d["Val4"]);
});

var rangeX=d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.2).domain(slots);
var rangeY=d3.scale.linear().range([h, 0]).domain([0, (maxval+50)]);
var axis_x=d3.svg.axis().scale(rangeX).tickSize(2).ticks(4);
var axis_y=d3.svg.axis().scale(rangeY).tickSize(2).orient("left");

p.append("g").call(axis_x).attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h) + ")");;
p.append("g").call(axis_y).attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                .x(slots, function(slots, i){return xScale(slots[i]);})
                .y(newdata, function (d, i){return yScale(d["Data "+(i+1)]);})

p.selectAll("line").attr("d", lineGen()).attr("stroke", "red").attr("stroke-width", 2).attr("fill", "none");
```

I know the "lineGen" function cannot be used the way I am using, I cant have the "slots" & "newdata" passed like this in "x" & "y". But was giving a try.
Can somebody guide me what could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution.  First, use a `d3.csv` `.row` to organize the data into an object of `key: [values]` where key is your x, y and z and values is an array of val1, val2, ...

```
d3.csv("data.csv")
  .row(function(d) {
    return {
      key: d.Name,
      values: [+d.val1, +d.val2, +d.val3, +d.val4]
    };
  })
  .get(function(error, data) {
     // draw plot
  }
```

Then your line generator is simply:

```
    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d,i) { return rangeX(slots[i]); })
      .y(function(d,i) { return rangeY(d); });
```

And you draw each line as:

```
    var g = p.selectAll(".lineGroup")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "lineGroup"); 

    g.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d,i) {
        return color(i);
      })
      .attr("fill","none");
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/qW77DpbScddXraajNFet?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks....it did show me lines row-wise....One more thing wud like to ask, what if I want to show chart of only one variable at a time...like I have a drop down menu, i select "x" from there and it shows line chart for only x.
As you can see in my code, I have filtered the data, according to choice, and stored in "newdata". what if instead of the whole csv file, i just want to use the data in "newdata" and plot chart. I cant use the row() as its for csv file. So is it possible some way?

Comment: @Sush, instead of resetting the data and redrawing, why not just hide/show lines based on selection?  See updated example: http://plnkr.co/edit/qW77DpbScddXraajNFet?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot!! That worked.... I know I am asking too much but one more thing I wanted to ask...I have added axes to the chart too, but the values on x-axis(slots) are not in sync with the points of graph....Also, the y-axis is not visible, even though i can see it on mozilla. Here is the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/GAtSXKRqQD2t9aKW25sC?p=preview

Comment: @Sush, yaxis is because you transformed the svg, instead svg should run full width/height, you add a g and transform that.  xaxis is because you are using `rangeBands`, you want `rangePoints`, updated here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lpFROOKgifTWYeFbrZBB?p=preview

Comment: ohhh....Well I was wondering why weird behaviour on chrome when its fine on mozilla....thank you so much for helping me out :)